# Bash, sed, remove last line for every cycle

Tags: bash, uninstall, sed

**Issue**

How can I remove last line for this `sed` cycle?

```
sed -n '/## bash, file, re/,/##/p' bash.kb
```

In my case, it shows me the last line too, last line with `##` string, which I need to remove.

Example.

Source file `bash.kb`, this is text file.

```
...

## bash, file, remove last character on every line
sed 's/.$//' $file

## bash, files, watch only today's modified files
some command.
some 2nd command.

## bash, file, remove duplicate rows by column 1
sort -u -t, -k1,1 $file

## bash, file, exclude
command exclude
command exclude 2

## bash, file, remove all whitespaces from file
command
...
```

When I enter this command.

```
sed -n '/## bash, file, re/,/##/p' bash.kb
```

It will search for `## bash, file, re` and display output until next `##`, so with next `##` head line, which I need to remove.

```
## bash, file, remove last character on every line
sed 's/.$//' $file

## bash, files, watch only today's modified files
## bash, file, remove duplicate rows by column 1
sort -u -t, -k1,1 $file

## bash, file, exclude
## bash, file, remove all whitespaces from file
command
```

Output should be like this (implement `sed '$d'` to every cycle? But how?).

```
## bash, file, remove last character on every line
sed 's/.$//' $file

## bash, file, remove duplicate rows by column 1
sort -u -t, -k1,1 $file

## bash, file, remove all whitespaces from file
command
```

Thanks.

Comment: @Melebius See update please. Is it more clear? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your input file has an empty line before every `##` line and only there, you can specify an empty line as the end of your range:

```
sed -n '/## bash, file, re/,/^$/p' bash.kb
```

`^$` matches a line that has the beginning (`^`), the end of the line (`$`) and nothing in between.

Comment: Yes, this is it. I didn't know how can I insert this. Thanks.